# Perfect TOEFL reading/writing/listening scores but low speaking score due to stutter. How will this affect PhD admissions?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, language-exams

I am fairly comfortable with English as a second language and have been studying at schools with English as the primary language for the last 9 years. I also have multiple semesters worth of experience TA'ing for CS courses in English (conducting lab sessions, giving short lectures etc.).

I recently took TOEFL and obtained scores around 28-29 for reading, writing, and listening sections.

However, I received a 17 in the speaking section. Since I can normally speak English comfortably in casual and academic settings, I believe this low result was due to the automatic grader interpreting my stutter as a sign of inadequacy.

How much would a low grade in the speaking section of TOEFL affect my overall profile when applying for a CS PhD in the US?

Thanks for any answers in advance.

Comment: I doubt this question can be answered because it depends on the admissions practices of the particular university.  Some universities will see a student with a disability as something that will improve their university by bringing in a new perspective.  Other universities will only look at the test score and ignore the context.  You can contact the university's accessibility or disability support office for information.

Comment: You can apply to have the speaking section omitted, if you wish.  I did not read the details, but I think you would have to take the test again.  https://www.ets.org/s/toefl/pdf/bulletin_supplement_test_takers_with_disabilities_health_needs_2021-2022.pdf

Comment: I have seen many CS PhD programs in the US have minimum requirements specifically on the speaking score to be eligible to be a TA. Some of them require taking a separate test after joining if the min. is not met. I have even seen programs impose very high requirements on speaking scores just to apply. E.g. MS CS, Cornell requires 28(!) : https://www.cs.cornell.edu/ms/admissions . So by default, I think this could put you at a disadvantage, but I am not familiar with the inner workings of the admissions process and whether there is any recourse available for cases like yours to give any advice.

Comment: Check the minimum requirements of the places you want to apply to first.

Comment: Is your stutter professionally diagnosed and language-independent? ETS may have accommodations if so (though this won't help with your past score). Also, if English was the exclusive language at your undergraduate institution you may be exempt from needing to submit TOEFL scores at some institutions (eg: https://grad.wisc.edu/apply/requirements/ "Applicants are exempt if:
English is the exclusive language of instruction at the undergraduate institution")

Comment: Just check whatever the score is for the place which you need to get into, it might be a lot lower than you would expect.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As in a comment by @GoodDeeds: in my U.S. R1 large state univ, my math dept has a cut-off of 23 for the spoken part of the TOEFL (=test of English as a foreign language), regardless of the rest of the application. Sometimes a 22 can make the cut, if faculty advocate for the applicant. Most of our grad students are supported as TAs (teaching assistants).

Although I've been involved in our grad admissions for a long time, I do not recall ever seeing a claim that a low speaking TOEFL score was due to a stutter or similar. I don't think we have any system in place for detecting such a claim, either! ... so an application with such a TOEFL score might not get read closely enough for any admissions people to see the explanation, etc.

To have admissions people think about this, you'll need to make a prominent point of it in a cover letter or elsewhere. And/or a direct communication with the Director of Grad Studies in the dept you're applying to, alerting them to the issue.

Answer (score 6):

I was in a very similar situation, except that it was the IELTS rather than the TOEFL for me, and that I wanted to apply to PhD programmes in the UK, rather than the US. It all worked out fine.

The role of a language test in PhD admissions is, in my experience, a binary measure. An applicant needs to be sufficiently proficient to be considered; but you cannot outcompete another candidate by being better in the language. It also seems to be rather common to handle the language certification towards the end of the process by making a conditional offer that needs a sufficiently good language test to be converted into an unconditional offer.

Thus, I believe that if your application material is otherwise strong, you can expect a conditional offer with the requirement to submit a better language certificate. At that point, you get in touch with the department and talk them into waving the requirement (actually talking rather than emailing probably works better, as they'll see that you can actually speak English and just stutter). That's how I did it.

Answer (score 0):

Given your past experience (as a TA), I'd guess it won't matter at all. Presumably you have developed some coping/compensation strategies  to effectively deal with it.

Perhaps you should indicate in a cover letter that you stutter, that it probably negatively affects an oral test score, and that you are happy to demonstrate that IRL you can communicate more effectively than the test indicates.

The US is also pretty good about not discriminating against people with such issues. A lot of that is enshrined in law. See [this](https://www2.ed.gov/about/offices/list/ocr/frontpage/faq/disability.html) for example.

But long term anything you can do to become an effective speaker will serve your career interests. But that is true of everyone.

Comment: Discrimination against people with disabilities is widespread in the US (and elsewhere).  It's just not obvious discrimination.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist, so, you seem to think that admissions committees in particular are full of folks willing to discriminate in a case like this. Would you be willing to take them to task if they did? I think your comment is irrelevant to the question asked and to the answer given.

Comment: I don't think this is true in general. Many US CS PhD programs impose minimum cutoffs specifically on speaking scores for admission, and some have higher cutoffs for allowing the student to be a TA. The cutoffs, especially for the latter, are often 25+, so 17 is well below that. Your second paragraph might be important though, I don't know what accommodations are provided to avoid discrimination in such cases.

Comment: @GoodDeeds, I don't know, but suspect that the verbal test is designed to catch entirely different things. At worst, I think the OP would be asked and can explain and demonstrate. A person who stutters can be entirely articulate, I think.

Comment: @Buffy If you think my comment is irrelevant then I suggest this sentence is also irrelevant and should be edited or removed: "The US is also pretty good about not discriminating against people with such issues."

Comment: Please take the personal out of the comment section, as well as discussion. Buffy, and Anonymous Physicist, you've both high enough rep to know better. Please, AP, if you disagree with Buffy's answer, down-vote it and write your own.